# Populate ArrayList based on checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, arraylist

I'm trying to find a way to send an email to selected recipients based on whether or not their email has been checked. We have a database with the emails in, and I've manually added a checkbox to resultant table. On clicking "Send", I want the email to send to those people based on whether or not they've been checked.

I thought the best way to do this would be to create an **ArrayList**, and then use **message.CC.Add(emailArray)**, but that gives invalid arguments. 
I then tried

```
string Email = emailArray.ToString() 
//and then 
message.CC.Add(email)
```

which didn't give errors, but it only sends to whomever clicks the button, IE myself or another colleague, and doesn't add the CCs. SMTP etc is all correct, as the email will send, just not to the ticked recipients.

```
ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();
                if (Request.Form["chkBox"].Equals(true))
                {
                    emailArray.Add(db.tblMailRecipients.Include(t => t.Email));
                }
                string email = emailArray.ToString();
                message.To.Add(email);
                smtp.Send(message);
                Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
```

The above code shows where I'm trying to get the emails and put it into the Arraylist.

Is it to do with how I'm getting the checkbox value and then relating (or not?) that to the row in the table?

We're using ASP.NET MVC with C#.

Any help would be appreciated :).

Thanks

**Update**
The following code is for the page listing recipients with the checkboxes:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "BulkMail", FormMethod.Post))
 { 
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastEmailDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            Check
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastEmailDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="chkBox" name="chkBox" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.MailRecipientId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.MailRecipientId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.MailRecipientId })
        </td>
    </tr> 
}
</table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

The message is hardcoded in the send mail function at the moment.

Comment: Provide your markup code which shows your checkbox code.

Comment: Will update the original post with it

Comment: Your checkboxes do not have a `value` attribute so there is no value to post back! (best guess it would need to be `<input name="chkBox type="checkbox" value="@item.MailRecipientId" />` (note do not add an `id` attribute). The the controller method would need a parameter `int[] chkBox` which on postback would contain an array of the selected recipients. But the correct approach is a view model as suggested by Dawood Awan's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the lack of interaction with this thread, had other stuff come up which was urgently needed. Firstly, thanks for all your help. I had a look today and came up with the following solution:

Add

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" value="@item.Email" />
```

into the view where emails etc can be selected. I then added:

```
message.Bcc.Add(Request.Form["chkBox"])
```

To the controller for the SMTP etc, and it seems to work pretty well :).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
<input id="chkBox" name="chkBox" type="checkbox" />
```

Inside a `foreach` loop, which will repeat the `id="chkBox"`, generating invalid HTML.

What you should do is create a Property in your Model. e.g.

```
public bool isChecked {get;set;}
```

Then display your Model using `forloop`: MVC Model binder requires the fields to be in the form: `[0].PropertyName`

```
    @for(var i =0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
        <tr>
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].LastName)
            </td>


...... Removed HTML
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].isChecked)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model[i].MailRecipientId }) |
..... Removed HTML
            </td>
        </tr> 
    }
```

When you Submit the Form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmail(List<CLASS_NAME> model)
{

var emails = model.Where(s => s.isChecked).Select(s => s.Email).ToArray();
............/////

}
```